# Hibernate not making insertions

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to save some data into a a database with hibernate but even the  console log doesn't show any error, the query it's not executed.

i tried insertion with a class (Dao Implementation)

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("sfGas")
    SessionFactory sf;

    Session session;    

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {

        try{
            Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(cliente);
            session.getTransaction().commit(); 

            System.out.println( "EXITO::INSERCION ");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

even i tried with native sql:

```
public void setCliente(JSONObject cliente) {

        String nombre = cliente.getString("nombre");
        String apellidos = cliente.getString("apellidos");
        String sexo = cliente.getString("sexo");
        String email = cliente.getString("email");
        String area = cliente.getString("area");
        String puesto = cliente.getString("puesto");
        int delegacion = cliente.getInt("delegacion");

        try{
            Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();

            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO cliente(id_delegacion, nombre, apellidos, email, sexo, area, puesto)"
                    +"VALUES ("+delegacion+","+ nombre+", "+apellidos+","+email+", "+sexo+", "+area+", "+puesto+");");


            System.out.println( "EXITO::INSERCION ");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Already checked that the user for the database has the privileges to make insertions on the table. what i'm missing here?

Comment: try `session.persist(cliente);`

Comment: @redflar3 nothing, still not inserting

Answer (score 0):

During updating/deleting something in database, you should also execute your query: `query.executeUpdate()`

Comment: No, that gives me this error [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/paterlinimatias/hibernate-error-quot-could-not-execute-native-bulk-manipulation-query-quot)